# Divide column 1 with column 2 for every 2 columns in a df

Tags: python, pandas

Hi im trying to divide column 1 with column 2 for every 2 columns in a df and assign the divided values to a new df. Here is the df:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jb7F.png)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Better include a short sample of the dataframe as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link. Also show what you tried already as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if i%2 == 0:
        new_df[col] = df[col]/df[df.columns[i+1]]
```

Comment: thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
i = 1
while i < df.shape[1]:
    new_df['col_'+ str(i)] = df[df.columns[i-1]] / df[df.columns[i]]
    i += 2
```